# getting properties of dynamic type c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

Consider the following code:

```
foreach (Type formType in allFormsToLoopThrough)
            {
                var nonPriorityForm = _context.Query(formType);
                foreach (var nonpriority in nonPriorityForm)
                {

                    var name = nonpriority.GetType().Name;

                    MyWorkAssignmentDTO form = new MyWorkAssignmentDTO
                    {
                        FormName = formType.Name
                        Id = nonpriority.Id

                    };

                }
            }
```

This snippet is looping thought a list of types. 
Each type is taken from the list and passed to a Query function that returns an IQueryable - basically a list of records in a given table in a database that matches the type.

Then for each of the record sets that come back, I want to loop through those and from each create a new instance of MyWorkAssignmentDTO. I am only interested in a form name (which I can get from formType) but I cannot get nonpriority.Id

I know for sure that every nonpriority will have an Id once it is resolved in the loop.
What I can't do is implement this to work at run time.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why can't you get the nonpriority.Id?

Comment: when i try to compile i get the error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? - i think it's because nonpriorityForm will be a different type on each loop assigned at run time. it isn't an IQueryable<ConcreteType> it's an IQueryable<formType> so i think the compiler doesn't know that there is an Id property available. I know that will always be the case, but I don't know how to tell the compiler there will always be an Id... if you see?

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without more detail. It sounds like `nonPriorityForm` is a list of objects? If they're all a 'formType' is there a base class or interface that could be used with generics to allow the property to be retrieved? So `nonPriorityForm` would be a `List<T> where T : IFormType`? Or have you considered using reflection to get the Id property, as you know it's there?

Comment: hi stuartd - thanks for the feedback. I think i'll try the generic route. I had considered reflection too and I have a link or two bookmarked. this gives me direction. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the *dynamic* keyword instead of var. While I lose compile time validation, this gets me over the line when I know for sure there will be an Id.

```
dynamic nonPriorityForm = _context.Query(formType);
```